# How to convert yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss?

Tags: php, timestamp

Paypal returns a timestamp of the following format:

```
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ
```

And I don't quite know what to do with it...

How can I convert it to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss using my local timezone in php?

I'm tempted to `preg_replace` the mysterious letters, but something tells me there must a better way. There also appears to be 8 hours difference to my zone which I'm not sure how to substract.

Comment: nothing mysterious about? T is timezone abbreviation and Z is timezone offset, just create a timestamp out of it and use date() to make out of it whatever you want ..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class to do your magic.

```
$date = new DateTime('2012-09-09T21:24:34Z');
$date->format('Y-m-d'); # read format from date() function
```

Comment: Sure, here it is: `[TIMESTAMP] => 2012-09-09T21:24:34Z` There appears to be Zero offset, though I've heard this format may allow for some number offset, near to `Z`.

Comment: Yup this is working too, thanks! `$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Comment: @Anonymous Look up [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for the valid time formats. "Z" is equivalent to "+00" or "+00:00" or "+0000". Hopefully DateTime (or your code) understands timezones.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) to get a UNIX timestamp. From there you can do whatever you need: `DateTime` object, `date()`, etc.

Example with `date()`:

```
echo date('r', strtotime('2012-09-10T10:00:00Z'));
```

Comment: The strtotime() and date() functions are not recommended anymore. Use the DateTime class.